Compile error: Expected function or variable
I have an Interface called IHuman and have 2 classes implementing it, namely cMan and cWoman. I have a Test module to test the code as shown below:
Test module
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Man As IHuman
Dim Woman As IHuman

Set Man = New cMan
Debug.Print Man.ManMessage
Debug.Print Man.WomanMessage

Set Woman = New cWoman
Debug.Print Woman.WomanMessage
Debug.Print Woman.ManMessage

End Sub

IHuman Interface
Option Explicit

Public Sub ManMessage()
End Sub

Public Sub WomanMessage()
End Sub

cMan Class
Option Explicit

Implements IHuman

Private Sub IHuman_ManMessage()
    Debug.Print "I am a Man."
End Sub

Private Sub IHuman_WomanMessage()
    Debug.Print "I am NOT a Woman."
End Sub

cWoman Class
Option Explicit

Implements IHuman

Private Sub IHuman_ManMessage()
    Debug.Print "I am NOT a Man."
End Sub

Private Sub IHuman_WomanMessage()
    Debug.Print "I am a Woman."
End Sub

When running the Test module, i am getting the following error:
Compile error: Expected Function or variable

on line Debug.Print Man.ManMessage in Test module.
I am on Excel 365 for Mac latest version. Any idea what could be the issue?

ManMessage is a Sub. You can't use it with Debug.Print since it doesn't return anything.

@Rory i am unable to use a msgbox also. How can i modify it?

Just call it from your main module - Man.ManMessage rather than Debug.Print Man.ManMessage

Same problem - MsgBox expects a value to display and your sub doesn't return one. As Darren said, just call it (the sub does a Debug.Print anyway)

Or you could update your subs to functions that return a string:  Private Function IHuman_ManMessage() As String: IHuman_ManMessage = "I am a man": End Function - have to update the interface as well.

Just one question: if i make the 2 subs or functions in interface as Friend, and run the code, it results in an error and Excel crashes. Why? Is it possible to add a Friend function inside the interface, or not?

Interfaces are best used as parameters to methods.
cMan class
Option Explicit

Implements IHuman

Private Sub IHuman_Message()
    Debug.Print "I am a Man."
End Sub

cWoman class
Option Explicit

Implements IHuman

Private Sub IHuman_Message()
    Debug.Print "I am a Woman."
End Sub

IHuman Interface
Option Explicit

Public Sub Message()
End Sub

Test module
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Person1 As cMan
Dim Person2 As cWoman

Set Person1 = New cMan
Set Person2 = New cWoman

reportGender Person1
reportGender Person2

End Sub

Sub ReportGender(ByRef ipHuman as IHuman)
    ipHuman.Message   ' Edit/instead of Debug.Print ipHuman.Message
End Sub


Interesting! If i change the Public Sub to a Friend Sub in the Interface, will it work?

Interface methods are inherently public.  That's the whole reason for their existence.  What is the reason for you wanting to confine your interface to the Project.

The debug.print statement returns an Expected function or variable error in the ReportGender procedure.  Just ipHuman.Message works as IHuman_Message contains the debug.print command.

I'm definitely not an expert on interfaces, but shouldn't Person1 and Person2 be declared as IHuman and set as cMan and cWoman?  The code works either way, but not sure what is the correct way.

No. That would defeat the whole point of an interface, which is different types with common methods defined by the interface.

Took the liberty to correct Debug.Print ipHuman.Message due to @DarrenBartrup-Cook 's comment

Cheers.  It was just a quick suggestion.  I didn't have time to test.

The problem is how Debug.Print is used.
It is supposed to be called like Debug.Print <something>, where the <something> can be a variable or result returned from a function.
However Debug.Print will fail when called like Debug.Print <Sub call> because Sub call is neither of those two.
Example:
Sub main()
    Debug.Print test1() ' Compile error : Expected Function or variable
    Debug.Print test2() ' Compiles fine as test2 is function

    Dim someValue
    someValue = "Some value"
    Debug.Print someValue ' Compiles fine as someValue is variable

    Debug.Print "Some other value" ' Compiles fine as well :)
End Sub

Sub test1()

End Sub

Function test2()
   
End Function

So in your code just remove the second Debug.Print
Debug.Print Man.ManMessage should be just Man.ManMessage.
Sub Test()

Dim Man As IHuman
Dim Woman As IHuman

Set Man = New cMan
Man.ManMessage
Man.WomanMessage

Set Woman = New cWoman
Woman.WomanMessage
Woman.ManMessage

End Sub

